# Kali video card drivers problem

Tags: drivers, kali-linux, nvidia

Can you please help me with kali nvidia-driver installation? I tried it many times but unsuccessfully. When I launched the OS from the hard drive, I could install the driver and it worked fine on nvidia. But now I installed the OS and tried to install nvidia-driver by the manual. At first, I couldn't start gui when the driver was launched after reboot. It just showed that something is wrong. I used apt-get purge to uninstall and it turned to work fine. Then, I tried to install by full manual and when I used these lines:

```
apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
apt-get install nvidia-kernel-dkms
sed 's/quiet/quiet nouveau.modeset=0/g' -i /etc/default/grub
update-grub
```

This didn't even let me to know what is wrong it just didn't allow me to watch any gui. I deleted nvidia-driver.
Now I can see something but it is only for 4:3 screens. So, it looks weird on my one.
So, how to install nvidia-driver successfully or at least return 16:9 screen mode?

Comment: Could you post the output of this file? `lspci -v`